# jQuery: toggling visibility of answers in a Q&A list generated in php by clicking on questions

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, foreach, count

I've a list of Q&A generated by php. Number of questions and answers in faq will be variable. With javascript I would like to toggle visibility of the answer, so when a user clicks on the question it will be displayed. With php I can count questions and answers and use the count  integer to assign a id or link to the question or a class/id or anchor to the answers. However I'm not sure how to generate the same count in a separate javascript.... I'm not too javascript savvy :(

```
echo'<dl id="faq-list">';
$i = 1;
foreach(get_field('faq_qa') as $faq) :
    $count = $i++;
    echo'<dt class="question"><a href="#answer-'.$count.'">'.$faq['faq_question'].'</a></dt><dd class="answer answer-'.$count.'">'.$faq['faq_answer'].'</dd>';
endforeach;
echo'</dl>';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your HTML structure is not going to change, you can bind a `click` event handler to the `dt` elements and simply show the following sibling (the `dd`):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#faq-list").on("click", "dt.question", function() {
        $(this).next().show();
    });
});
```

The above will require jQuery 1.7+ as it uses the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method. If you are using an older version, look at [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), or just use [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

I have selected the parent `#faq-list` element and bound the event handler there because it's more efficient than binding many event handlers to all of the separate `dt` elements. This way, there is one event handler which checks to see if the event originated on a matching `dt.question` element. This is possible since events bubble up the DOM from where they originated (the event originates on a `dt`, and bubbles up to the parent, which is `#faq-list`).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all your `dd` elements are hidden by CSS on page load, try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('dt.question').on('click', function() {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some jQuery

```
$('#question-1').click(function() {
  $('.answer-1').show('slow');
});
```

However you will need to identify also your question with a unique id like this

```
<dt class="question question-'.$count.'">
```

Comment: that's my idea too, I do have $count in my code as you can see above; however I'm not sure how to "count" in javascript as well; if I use the jquery function as suggested above, wouldn't that work only for question/answer set #1 ? how about if I have 8 QAs? or 20? or 32? etc.

Comment: @Fulvio - You don't need to "count" them in your JS. See my answer, which will work with all of the question/answer sets, regardless of how many there are.

Comment: You will need to set the numbers from 1 to 8 or 20 dynamically.